# Count the number occurrences of a special character in a string (while and for loops only, no functions)

Tags: python, string, for-loop, while-loop, count

My program has to count how many special characters are in a string using only while or for loops (not allowed to use built-in functions).

```
def compteMembres(s):

    special_chars = 'F' or '4' or 
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        q = 0
        if special_chars in s:
            q = q + 1                 
        i = i + 1       
    return q

s = input("Enter string: ")

compteMembres(s)
```

Comment: Hey. Can you be more specific, what you mean when you say special characters? not a number or a letter?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand when you mean special characters you intend chars that are not numbers or letters.
I update your code to find the number of the special characters in the string:

```
def compteMembres(s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if not ('a' <= s[i] <= 'z' or 'A' <= s[i] <= 'Z' or '0' <= s[i] <= '9'):
            count += 1
    return count


s = input("Enter string: ")
print(compteMembres(s))
```

I hope that is the answer you search. if you mean to other thing let me know.